# Image Zoom effect using Cloud Zoom jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to apply cloud zoom on a single image as in the below Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/7HDbz/

But it does not seems to be working. Someone have a look at this.
Here is another fiddle with working effects

http://jsfiddle.net/tuHuZ/1/

The original plugin usage is here.... http://www.professorcloud.com/mainsite/cloud-zoom.htm

Comment: I am sorry, This is the link http://www.professorcloud.com/mainsite/cloud-zoom.htm.. That is a jQuery plugin to apply zoom effect on images..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problems with your first fiddle (the non-working one) include:

- No space between the `src` and `class` attribute on your `<a>` tag
- Using `'` single quotes instead of `"` double-quotes for constructing the `<a>` tag
- Use of `prop` where `attr` should be used.  The former is only for properties where the value is irrelevant, such as `disabled`.
- General Tip: Use variable names that make sense -- e.g. use `src` for the image source instead of `x` (which could mean anything, and in fact suggests a number)
- General Tip: You should avoid having multiple `$(this)` calls.  Instead, set a local variable `$this` as shown

Here's the working corrected version: http://jsfiddle.net/6dR2k/ .